# Initialize a 1D or 2D array in shared memory

Tags: c, arrays, linux, posix, shared-memory

I am trying to initialize a 2D char array of strings into POSIX shared memory to be shared between 3 other processes.  There are plenty of tutorials on how to use a pointer to share a single string or an integer between processes, but I could find no examples on how to initialize 1D or 2D arrays using `mmap()`.  I have posted what I have so far below.  It is the first program, which creates the shared memory object and initialize the array `char files[20][2][100]` with the value `files[0][0][0] = '\0'`.

What is the proper method to initialize and share an array in C?

For context, I coded a simple version of this project (at the suggestion of helpful S.O. gurus) which does not use shared memory and combines all 4 processes (separated by `/**********/`) into one.  It's below.

I've asked a similar question involving structs in a previous post, but I was required to use a multidimensional array instead for my project.  Any insights on that answer would be helpful [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350679/initializing-an-array-of-structs-into-shared-memory).

Thanks.

**CODE SO FAR:** (program initializes shared memory object and array)

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char files [20][2][100]; 


    /* the size of shared memory object */
    int size = sizeof(files);

    /* name of the shared memory object */
    const char *name = "/PROJ4_SHARED_MEM";

    /* shared memory file descriptor */
    int shm_fd;

    /* pointer to shared memory obect */
    void *ptr;

    /* create the shared memory object */
    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDRW, 0666);

    /* configure the size of the shared memory object */
    ftruncate(shm_fd, size);

    /* memory map the shared memory object */
    ptr = mmap(0, size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

    /* save array to the shared memory object. */
    /*****WHERE I LOSE IT*****/

    return 0;
}
```

**CONTEXT PROGRAM:** (not POSIX)

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char files [20][2][100]; 
    files [0][0][0] = '\0';
    char file_name[100];

    char file_contents[100];
    char search[100];

    char answer;
    int again = 0;
    int counter;
    int i = 0;

    /**************************************************/

    while (again == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a filename:  ");
        scanf("%s", &file_name);
        getchar();
        printf("Enter file contents (string):  ");
        fgets (file_contents, 100, stdin);

        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if (files[i][0][0] == '\0')
            {
                strcpy(files[i][0],file_name);
                strcpy(files[i][1],file_contents);
                files [i+1][0][0] = '\0';       
                break;
            }
            else if (i == 19)
            {
                printf("ERROR: The directory is full.\n\n");
            }
        }

        counter++; 

        printf("Save another file y/n ?:  ");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);

        if (answer == 'n')
        {
            again = 1;
        }

    }
    printf("\n\n");
    again = 0;

    /**************************************************/

    printf("You have saved the following files:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (files[i][0][0] == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("%s \n", files[i][0]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    /**************************************************/

    printf("Would you like to open a file? (y/n) ?:  ");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    if (answer == 'n')
        again = 1;

    while (again == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a filename:  ");
        scanf(" %s", &file_name);

        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(files[i][0], file_name) == 0)
            {
                printf("%s \n", files[i][1]);       
                break;
            }
            else if (i == 19)
            {
                printf("ERROR: The file was not found.\n\n");
            }
        }

        printf("Search for another file (y/n) ?:  ");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);

        if (answer == 'n')
        {
            again = 1;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }


    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has a pointer to the shared memory 
therefore, like with any pointer, 
the code can access any specific item in the shared memory 
by indexing off that pointer.

```
#define INDEX_1_SIZE (20)
#define INDEX_2_SIZE (2)
#define INDEX_3_SIZE (100)
#define SIZE         (INDEX_1_SIZE * INDEX_2_SIZE * INDEX_3_SIZE)
ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
```

then:

```
int i, j, k; // loop counters

// initialize the shared memory to '\0'
for(i=0;i<INDEX_1_SIZE; i++_
{
    for(j=0; j<INDEX_2_SIZE; j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<INDEX_3_SIZE; k++)
        {
            ptr[i][j][k] = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

there are faster ways to perform the initialization to '\0'
for instance:

```
memset( ptr, '\0', SIZE );
```

There is no need for the local variable: 'files'

However, since a number of different processes can access the
shared memory at the same time,
the code needs a named semaphore that all the processes use
so only one process is accessing the shared memory at
any one time, to avoid 'race' conditions.
here is a good discussion, with example usage, for semaphores
    http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node26.html
the code should be checking for errors, something like this:
( of course, using your own variable names )

```
des_mutex = shm_open(MUTEX, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, mode);

if (des_mutex < 0)
{
    perror("failure on shm_open on des_mutex");
    exit(1);
}

if (ftruncate(des_mutex, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)) == -1)
{
    perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof pthread_cond_t\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Great info.  But I keep getting the following errors when I try to prt[i][j][k] or any other instance I try use it as an array:  "myformat.c:55: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
------myformat.c:55: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer"

Comment: Okay, I made a quick edit and it works great.  Instead of initializing the pointer at `void *ptr;` I made it `char (*ptr)[20][2];`.  Thanks, I've already got the rest of the programs up and running.  For my purposes, the semaphores where unecessary.  Each consumer program completes before the others run, so no race conditions.  But for most situations, I know that wouldn't be the case.  So good info all around.